# Do I need a paid Apple Developer account to obtain .p12 certification to push notification?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications

I'm just testing AWS Mobile Hub with iOS, to implement push notification feature AWS ask to upload .p12 certificate which can obtain by the Apple Developer web site, But according to the tutorials.

> Maintaining Identifiers, Devices, and Profiles

doesn't appear on my Apple Developer account (I'm using free Apple Developer account)

Do I need paid Apple Developer account (US$ 99) to get that feature ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you do. Push Notifications are only available for paid memberships, along with some other capabilities. See the footnote in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/). The .p12 certificate is the file you use to be able to push notifications to your application, so you need the paid membership.

Comment: Is paid account is mandatory for implementing `Sign in with apple` functionality ?

(i am using React Native to do so)

Answer (score 3):

Yes,
To upload certificate and implement Push Notifications in IOS, you need paid Apple Developer account (US$ 99).
Its the same for Whichever Mobile Hub you use like AWS, Azure,etc.