# Is paid apple developer account needed for implementing Login with Apple in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-sign-in

We are implementing `Sign in with apple` functionality in React Native with  [invertase/react-native-apple-authentication](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication)  . So, do we need paid apple developer account in order to implement the functionality (even in development).

Their is similar kind of question here
[Do I need a paid Apple Developer account to obtain .p12 certification to push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304797/do-i-need-a-paid-apple-developer-account-to-obtain-p12-certification-to-push-no)

But, In above mentioned question clarifies : `Push Notification` requires the paid developer account, but does same applies for `Sign in with apple` functionality.

React Native version :

[image: React Native Version]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You need to have `Sign in with Apple` capability added to your certificates without that you won't be able to test your code, you can implement it but can not test it so you'll need that in order to implement and check if it's working or not